# "Splashless" app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, splash-screen

I noticed that many iPhone apps like Instagram and Twitter don't have a splash screen, they show an empty version of the UI while the app is loading; then the interface is filled with the rest of the elements. Is it a simple trick that involves a normal splash screen simulating the interface of the app?

Comment: This is actually what Apple themselves have defined the `Default.png` as- an empty snapshot of the UI of the first screen while it loads.

Comment: You might find my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191807/presenting-modalviewcontroller-on-resume-from-background-avoiding-flash-of-cont/11192791#11192791) SO thread usefull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is simply an image replicating the look of the app.

Apple recommends doing such a trick to lessen the perceived loading time of the app (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `default.png` is **not** meant to be a splashscreen! The human interface guidelines state that you should use a screenshot of your user interface with controls disabled. There is no trick to do this because the `default.png` is displayed while your app loads, so there is no UI to display. You have to take the screenshot yourself with controls disabled and then use it as the `default.png`